# Is the Emperor in Saberhagens Book of Swords immune to magic

Tags: book-of-swords

I only read the *Books of Swords* trilogy, but not the *Books of Lost Swords* — so maybe there is an answer to my question somewhere. All the following cites are from book 3.

In one scene Draffut told Mark that he thinks that Sightblinder did not deceive the Emperor a moment. This would give some reason regarding that the Emperor is even immune to the magic of the Swords.

When visiting Yambu in one of the last chapters, he said to Yambu, that if she decides to draw the Sword Soulcutter, he will leave.

In one of the last chapters, the Emperor walked onto the war area where Vilkata and Yambu trying to fight with Mindsword and Soulcutter. It is described that he rode on Draffut and then walked with a sword in his hand to Yambu. I asked myself, what Sword it is which is in his hands (as it isn't described in detail in the book). Of course it might be just an ordinary sword — in the first book he is described to have a short sword on his belt. It is known that Draffut received Woundhealer, which he might have given to the Emperor. Other than this, it might of course be Shieldbreaker, which would negates the effects of both Mindsword and Soulcutter against him...

But if it is Shieldbreaker, then he is most probably not immune to the magic of the Swords (or at least it is what the Emperor is thinking). Are there any other hints or a clarification somewhere else whether the Emperor is actually immune to magic (especially to the magic of the Swords)?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  It is a bit confusing what you're asking; you start asking if the Emperor is immune to magic, then ask what sword he's wielding, then if it's Shieldbreaker, then you ask if the Emperor _believes_ he is immune.  You should clean this up so it is a single question, or at least make clear what the _primary_ question you're asking is.

Comment: The reason for this sub-question is my suspicion that the Emperor is not immune to magic. If he actually needs the Sword Shieldbreaker to be immune from the effects of Soulcutter, then we must assume that he actually isn't immune to all magic - all other citations would make us believe that no magic will affect him (even the magic of the Swords). So I wouldn't be sure what is the right question, because I think all those questions are related.

Answer (score 3):

I can give you the "Word of God" answer, since my brother and I got into an e-mail correspondence with Fred Saberhagen shortly before his death in 2007.  The nature of the Emperor was one of the specific things that my brother asked the author about.  We were dissatisfied with what *The Last Book of Swords* appeared to be saying about the Emperor; my brother, in particular, had another theory—that the Emperor was an evolved version of Rolf, the hero of the *Empire of the East* novels.  However, Saberhagen confirmed that he meant what he had implied about the nature of the Emperor in *The Last Book of Swords*—that the Emperor was **God** (the real God, not the likes of Vulcan and company).  Ipso facto, then, the Emperor would be omnipotent and thus immune to all the swords' magical powers (if he chose to be).

That's not a very satisfying answer, however.  Personally, I do not think that this was what Saberhagen had in mind when he started writing the books.  In a fairly candid e-mail, he admitted that the *Books of Swords* were far more profitable for him than anything he had written before.  When it was released, *The First Book of Swords* was marketed like an incipient bestseller, which none of his books had been before.  Tor promoted the book with special displays in bookstores, and the sword printed on the cover was textured.  Saberhagen said that there was a tremendous financial incentive to continue writing *Swords* books after the first three, and that was part of what kept him writing them for so long.

Reading between the lines of our correspondence, as well as the later *Swords* books (which I did not read all of, although my brother did), we inferred that Saberhagen's narrative had diverged strongly from his original conception of the series while he was working on *The Third Book of Swords*.  When he started the series, he had intended it to be three books, but by the time he was done with *The Third Book of Swords*, he had decided that there would be more.  (Notice that toward the end of the *Third Book*, he destroys two of the swords:  Townsaver, about which he had effectively already written a whole book; and Doomgiver, which he seeminlgy recognized that he had not been able to write a worthy narrative about in the *Third Book of Swords*).

Saberhagen had to make up a lost material to fill out the additional books that he planned on writing.  As a result, the character of the series changes quite a bit, and *The First Book of Swords* and *The Second Book of Swords* seem to describe a somewhat different cosmology from that in the later books.  Some of the events in *The Third Book of Swords* certainly seem to have been planned from the beginning:  Mindsword enslaving the gods, Draffut receiving Woundhealer at the end, and the revelation of the Emperor as Mark's father—Mark having been intentionally sired as a child whose destiny would be caught up with that of the twelve swords.  Unfortunately, it was never made clear what the nature of the Emperor was originally intended to be; if Saberhagen had even had something specific in mind when he wrote the first two volumes (before he changed his mind and decided the Emperor was God) he refused to say so to his fans.  Nevertheless, we can learn a bit about the nature of the Emperor, and his relation to Sightblinder, from his early appearances in the series.

The Emperor was the original recipient of Sightblinder;* he was one "lowly and despised," according to the "Song of the Swords."  Twice in the course of the *First Book*, the Emperor appears, carrying Sightblinder.  This means he is in disguise, but the ways those disguises work are much more subtle than later in the series.  This is actually a common trend in fantasy series.  Fantastical elements that appear weird and idiosyncratic when they are first introduced often become routine parts of the setting over time, coming to operate according along "prosaic and businesslike,"** predicable lines.  Comparing the operation of Coinspinner and Sightblinder between *The First Book of Swords* and *The Third*, the swords' later functions become much more predictable and mechanical than they were when they were first introduced.  The Emperor first appears on the night of Jord's return from the mountains, when he impregnates Mala.  He is not disguised as anyone Mala should know or trust; instead, he appears to be wearing a leather mask, which Mala later comes to believe means that he was actually Duke Fraktin.  He reappears at the end of the book, and again, his disguise is explicitly visible to the person he is there to meet—his son, Mark.  While the Emperor is holding Sightblinder, Mark perceives him as his "father," in the garb of a clown; after the Emperor lets go of the sword, Mark just sees him as a clown in makeup, no longer recognizable.  The Emperor consistently appears as a *trickster* character, even when he does not possess Sightblinder.  He has magic of his own, and may even be older than the gods.  (This element, of course, was preserved in the conclusion that Saberhagen eventually wrote, as described in the lede paragraph above.)  So it may have been reasonable that, even under Saberhagen's original conception, that the Emperor might not be as susceptible to the powers of the swords as other beings.

*Saberhagen may have intended the sword the Emperor has at the end of the trilogy to have been Sightblinder again, but I don't know.

**A quote from Saberhagen's story "Inhuman Error."

Comment: Thanks for this complete and insightful answer to my question!

Comment: If the sword the Emperor carries on the battlefield would be Sightblinder, wouldn't Rostov see him as somebody he loves or fears? Rostov saw a grey robed man with mask, which is how the Emperor is usually described.

Perhaps the Emperor was really thought to be a mystery, similar to Tom Bombadil...